# Programmatically create shortcut keys combo for desktop "shortcut"

Tags: c#, .net, windows, installation, shortcut

Is there a way through code, or through the creation of a setup project (via VS), to create a desktop shortcut **with a keyboard shortcut pre-defined**?

[alt text http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/8066/shortcutce8.jpg](http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/8066/shortcutce8.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [IShellLink interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774950(VS.85).aspx), HotKey method to define a hotkey.